# German §4 BeschV visa (specialist visa) language requirements for applicant and spouse

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit

I have a simple question in regards to German long-term work visa §4 BeschV ('specialist') that I might be applying for. In the visa application I am encouraged to also apply for my spouse at the same time. However, I could not find much info on language requirements on the BeschV law or any info on family reunion for that matter except for AufenthG which is for residence permit and only exempts lang. requirements for EU BlueCard owners. Could it be that this decision is left to the embassies to decide on individual basis?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very fast response from the embassy and language requirements are as follows:

- For the applicant: No language required
- For the spouse: German A1 certificate is required

I was told that the A1 training and certification can be done by the time the spouse gets his or her visa. Even if more time is needed, 3 more months can be given for this after approving the visa. Exempt are persons who are prevented to attend the course due to disability or some other major factor.

In case of EU BlueCard none of this is required.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.